# Какое выбрать облачное хранилище?

Tags: файлы, хранение-данных, хранилище, облачное-хранилище

Нужно развернуть на рабочем компьютере облачное хранилище. Все пользователи находятся в подсети.

Яндекс.Диск, *Google Drive*, *Dropbox* - в принципе подходят идеально, за исключением того, что хранилище должно быть "у себя".

На всякий случай основные требования:

- Поддержка Windows, Linux (**клиенты для синхронизации папок**)
- Бесплатность
- Возможность доступа через веб-морду
- Элементарная система пользователей с паролями
- Разграничение папок для пользователей

Благодарю.

Comment: ownCloud. https://owncloud.org/

Comment: @kff забыл упомянуть что смотрел в его сторону, но почему то он меня оттолкнул. Надеялся найти ещё какие то варианты или решения. Если ничего не найду - придётся его взять. Спасибо.

Comment: есть ещё модификация ownCloud - [nextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/) и  [seafile](https://www.seafile.com/en/home/).

Comment: Не уверен, что точно понял требования, но похоже, что [**Tonido**](http://alternativeto.net/software/tonido/) — то, что Вам нужно. А вообще при выборе софта всегда смотрите альтернативы на AlternativeTo.Net. Очень много вариантов — облачных хранилищ. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных смотрел Tonido. Там очень силен упор на мобильные устройства, у меня же цель синхронизации файлов между папками на компьютерах.